# Cross-platform way to read data from multiple connections in single thread

Tags: tcp, network-programming, cross-platform, epoll

My application need to download several web-pages simultaneously and i know this is possible in a single thread because of experience with epoll programming in linux. Currently i use CURL to interact with HTTP but...

**update:** Discovered the curl's MULTI-interface: http://curl.haxx.se/libcurl/c/libcurl-multi.html I think question is resolved (-;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The cross-platform way is to use `select` or `poll` which are specified by POSIX.

Alternatively, and more efficiently, you could use a library. The main advantage of a library is that it can do things way more effectively than `select`, by employing system-specific mechanisms.

For example, a nice network library would probably use:

- `epoll` on Linux
- `kqueue` on FreeBSD
- `/dev/poll` on solaris
- `pollset` on AIX
- `iocp` on Win32
- etc

I think you can use [`asio`](http://think-async.com/) for C++ or [`libevent`](http://libevent.org/) for C.